How to add a custom react component to the Strapi rich text block content type?
I'm using a strapi CMS with my React application, and in addition to the standard blocks available in the JSON-based rich text editor, like paragraph, header or image, I want to be able to add my own react components that would be appropriately rendered on my website. I'm using blocks-react-renderer (https://github.com/strapi/blocks-react-renderer) to render my content, but I couldn't figure out how to properly add a new type of block to this JSON parser.

this is yet not supported

Strapi currently doesn't support this, one hack you can use is to reuse the code component of block renderer. You can pass the props or variables via plain text format and handle it accordingly
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BlocksRenderer
      content={content}
      blocks={{
        paragraph: ({ children }) => <p className="text-neutral900 max-w-prose">{children}</p>,
        link: ({ children, url }) => <Link to={url}>{children}</Link>,
        code: (props) => {
            return handleCustomComponent(props);
          },
      }}
      modifiers={{
        bold: ({ children }) => <strong>{children}</strong>,
        italic: ({ children }) => <span className="italic">{children}</span>,
      }}
    />
  );
};

Below is a example, where you can render a custom component, you can parse the plain text coming from api with some identifiers such as '\n' to create a dynamic structure where you can pass other customisations in the form of payload. With the identifier as '\n' you can parse the plain text and extract the required information and render accordingly

In the strapi editor you can add a code block and add the identifiers and payload in the form of plainText
const handleCustomComponent = (props: any) => {
   const parsedPlainText=parse(props.plainText)
   if(parsedPlainText[0]=='COMPoNENT_1') return <Component1/>
   else if(parsedPlainText[0]==='COMPONENT_2') 
    const payLoad=parsedPlainText[1]
   return <Component2 payload={payload}/>
}

